# How to only output turning points of a path for maze

Tags: python-3.x, path-finding

So I have an astar algorithm that outputs a path on a maze. But I only want the nodes (represented as tuples (row,column)) where you actually make a turn in the maze.

Ex.

```
path = [(10,0),(10,1),(9,1),(8,1),(8,2),(8,3),(7,3)] #given from astar alg  
path = [(10,0),(10,1),(8,1),(8,3),(7,3)] #desired output
```

Here's a part of my code:

```
for node in self.path:
            direction1 = (self.path[node][0] - self.path[node+1][0], self.path[node][1] - self.path[node+1][1])
            direction2 = (self.path[node+1][0] - self.path[node+2][0], self.path[node+1][1] - self.path[node+2][1])
            if direction1 == direction2:
                self.path.pop([node+1])
            elif direction1 == None:
                pass
            else:
                pass
```

Comment: do you get an error? if so what is the error?

Comment: actually, I can see a lot of things going wrong with that code, you use `node` as the indice, you pop out elements of the list while iterating over it, and you are not checking whether you are at the end of the list yet so `self.path[node+1]` could raise an `IndexError`.

Comment: Yeah, for some reason it doesn't give me an error but you're right: i did not take that into account.

Comment: I'm sorry... the code above does _not_ raise any errors? Then what is your actual question?

Comment: Never mind its completely wrong. Like you said, I'm looking at the tuples in the path and not the actual index for each tuple. My question is I have a path. I want only the turning points in the maze from start to goal. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to iterate over the indices of `self.path` use:

```
for node in range(len(self.path)):
```

but since you want to stop checking 2 before the end (so that `self.path[node+2]` will always be valid) just use:

```
for node in range(0,len(self.path)-2):
```

either way, deleting elements of the path as you iterate over it will likely cause issues so I'd recommend constructing the new path then replacing the old one:

```
new_path = [self.path[0]] #keep the first element since it will always be needed
for node in range(0,len(self.path)-2):
    direction1 = (self.path[node][0] - self.path[node+1][0], self.path[node][1] - self.path[node+1][1])
    direction2 = (self.path[node+1][0] - self.path[node+2][0], self.path[node+1][1] - self.path[node+2][1])
    if direction1 != direction2:
        new_path.append(self.path[node+1])
new_path.append(self.path[-1]) #add in the last element
self.path = new_path
```

but this is maybe more confusing since you have to deal with `node+1` more then `node` so you probably want to start at indice 1 and end at `len(self.path)-1` so you would use:

```
new_path = [self.path[0]] #keep the first element since it will always be needed
for node in range(1,len(self.path)-1):
    direction1 = (self.path[node-1][0] - self.path[node][0], self.path[node-1][1] - self.path[node][1])
    direction2 = (self.path[node][0] - self.path[node+1][0], self.path[node][1] - self.path[node+1][1])
    if direction1 != direction2:
        new_path.append(self.path[node])
new_path.append(self.path[-1]) #add in the last element
self.path = new_path
```

Comment: Thank you! This is awesome.